# ApiController override to access User.Claims

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, owin

I have a base api controller I'm inheriting from ApiController with. In it I'm overriding ExecuteAsync and looking to use some of the data stored in the Principal.Claims var. but it's empty before calling base.ExecuteAsync() and too late after calling it. I don't see anything else to override to help this?

```
public class ApiControllerBase : ApiController
{
    public MyUser CurrentUser { get; set; }

    public override Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // principal.claims is empty
        ClaimsPrincipal principal = (ClaimsPrincipal)RequestContext.Principal; // principal.claims is empty

        var rv = base.ExecuteAsync(controllerContext, cancellationToken);

        // principal.claims is now populated but the controller.action that inherits from this basecontroller has already fired and thrown an exception since CurrentUser is null.
        principal = (ClaimsPrincipal)RequestContext.Principal;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you need to override this method? What behavior you want to achieve?

Comment: I couldn't find another method in the pipeline to override. End goal is to have some properties on my base ApiController so that inheriting controllers can use them. The info I need to load those properties are in the Principal.Claims collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need access to claims in your controllers you can do the following:

```
public class MyUser 
{
    private readonly ClaimsIdentity _identity;

    public SeaUser(ClaimsIdentity identity)
    {
        _identity= identity;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Claim> Claims { get { return _identity.Claims; } }
}

public abstract class BaseController : ApiController
{
    private MyUser _user;

    public new MyUser User
    {
        get 
        { 
            return _user ?? (_user = User.Identity != null 
                                  ? new MyUser((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity) 
                                  : null); }
        }
    }
}
```

And then use User property wherever you need.

Assuming the request goes into the ApiController scope, the operation order is as below:

- The ExecuteAsync method of the ApiController is invoked.
- The Initialize method of the ApiController is invoked.
- The registered Action Selector is retrieved.
- The SelectAction method of the registered action selector is invoked.
  If only one action method is matched, the pipeline continues.
- All registered Filters for the selected action is retrieved.
- The Authorization Filters are called. The authorization filter can
  decide either to let the pipeline to continue executing or to
  terminate the pipeline.
- If Authorization Filters didn't terminate the request, action
  parameter bindings are performed.
- ApiController.ModelState is set.
- Action Filters are invoked. The Action Filters an decide either to
  let the pipeline to continue executing or terminate the pipeline.
- If Action Filters didn't terminate the request, registered Action
  Invoker is retrieved.
- The InvokeActionAsync method of the registered Action Invoker is
  called to invoked the selected action method.

Note: If any exception occurs from the execution of the Authorization Filters to the execution of the action method, the exception filters are be called.

There are a few more things which happen in between but this is very close to a complete view. Check out the [ApiController source code](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/436ae9643c21#src/System.Web.Http/ApiController.cs) for more information.

Comment: +1 This does work but I would like to know if there is a way to implement it like I'm trying to do above.

Comment: I added some notes to the answer. According to WebAPI execution pipeline - it's impossible to get the principal before `ExecuteAsync` has been called because it will be initialized inside this method.

Answer (score 0):

You can override OnActionExecuting(), which will be called each time you execute an action.

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var user = context.HttpContext.User;
        //store user.Claims in property so inherited controllers have access
        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }
```

Comment: That method doesn't exist on the System.Web.Http.ApiController

Comment: oops, I'm sorry.  My application is using ASP.Net Core 1.0, where there's a new Controller class

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (Thread.CurrentPrincipal)

```
public override Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var principal = Thread.CurrentPrincipal as ClaimsPrincipal;
    return base.ExecuteAsync(controllerContext, cancellationToken);
}
```

I'm not sure if the order of registration in IAppBuilder (Startup.Configuration) is important, but the first thing I register is the  Authentication middleware.

Comment: For me **principal.Claims.Any()** return false before running the base implementation.

Comment: You are able to retrieve claims at another stage? If not, are you 100% sure that claims was added when you created the ticket?

Comment: Yes. If I instead do

    var rv = base.ExecuteAsync(controllerContext, cancellationToken);
    principal.Claims // This now has the values.
    return rv;